# dom.setInterval not available on ScalaJS

Tags: scala.js

I'm following tutorial http://www.lihaoyi.com/hands-on-scala-js/#MakingaCanvasApp and it provides code :

```
  dom.setInterval(() => run, 50)
```

But this causes a compiler error :

```
object setInterval is not a member of package org.scalajs.dom
```

How to set the interval on the dom ? It appears this method has been removed instead of deprecated ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still available under `dom.window.setInterval`, I think.

However, you should use `scala.scalajs.js.timers.setInterval` instead:

```
import scala.scalajs.js

js.timers.setInterval(50) {
  run
}
```

Comment: "you should use scala.scalajs.js.timers.setInterval instead" - why?

Comment: Because it exposes a more Scala-esque API, and it does not require the dependency on `scalajs-dom`, which makes it more portable, so to speak.